# minimize norm of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, eigenvalues, nonlinear-optimization

I have the matrix Product $PAP^H$ and I need to minimize $\|(PAP^H)^{-1}\|^2$ (over $P$ and Frobenius norm).
$A$ is a positive definite Hermitian matrix and $P$ has the structure
$$P=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc} p_1 &0 &\ldots&\ldots& 0 \\ 0& p_2 &0 &\ldots&0 \\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\ 0& \ldots & \ldots & 0& p_M \end{array}\right]$$
where $p_m$ are $1 \times K$ vectors (consequently, $A$ is $MK \times MK$).

I have two cases:

1. $\|p_m\|^2 =1, \forall m$
2. $\sum_m \|p_m\|^2 =M$

Matlab converges to the same point no matter the starting position (both cases).
Any hope to solve in closed form?